# How to toggle (all) line numbers on or off

Tags: vim

Let's say I have some combination of:

```
" one if not both is usually on
set number         " could be on or off
set relativenumber " could be on or off
```

Is there a way to toggle these on/off without losing information (not knowing what is set -- i.e., I would like to make a simple keyboard shortcut to toggle the visibility of the current line-number selection)? For example if I have only `rnu` set and I do:

```
:set number!
```

It really doesn't help me at all, since I'll still have `rnu` set and there will still be a `line-number column` on the left. If so, how could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

- currently, I am mapping it to `<F7>` you can change the mapping if you like
- I am using the global variable, you can change the scope if it is required

This function will disable all line-number displays and restore to the old line number settings.

```
function! MagicNumberToggle() abort
    if &nu + &rnu == 0
        let &nu = g:old_nu
        let &rnu = g:old_rnu
    else
        let g:old_nu = &nu
        let g:old_rnu = &rnu
        let &nu = 0
        let &rnu =0
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <F7> :call MagicNumberToggle()<cr>
```

Comment: awesome. This is like black magic the vimscript but so cool. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I've posted a sort of follow-up questions here on how to enter/exit 'modes' from this function, or if it's possible.

Comment: @David542 I don't see the follow-up questions. what do you mean modes?

Answer (score 0):

The one liner solution

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-n> :let [&nu, &rnu] = [!&rnu, &nu+&rnu==1]<cr>
```

To understand what happens try:

```
:echo [&nu, !&rnu]

&nu ............. gets the value of number
!&rnu ........... the oposite value of relative number
```

For more `:h nu`

Comment: thanks for this. It works in some cases, but not others (for example if only have absolute numbers). It seems to toggle between three states.

Comment: But [@David542](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651174/david542), you can adapt the logic to only two values.